# How to stop job which is executed from screen?

Tags: centos, terminal-server

I have started `npm start` with screen for make node instant executable forever. but now I want to stop npm process. so how can I stop it?

I have executed below commands

```
> screen
> npm start
```

then pressed CTRL+A and then CTRL+D for closing screen session and then exit from terminal.

Now, how can I stop that npm job?

Comment: I have tried with kill <process id of node>

Comment: `kill` should have terminated the process, does it wait for a user input? or releasing a file descriptor? what is the node process output when killed?

Answer (score 1):

With <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> you detach a screen session.

You typically want to resume that detached screen session, `screen -r [pid.sessionname]`  after which among others you can terminate your program with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I got solution my self from googling it

I have see screen session name  if by `screen -list` command

then I have executed command `screen -X -S "sessionname" quit`

Thanks for your helps :)